# IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2019 with CMake Project and IAR Compiler

Tags: c++, c, cmake, intellisense, iar

So I have a CMake project which I open in Visual Studio 2019 with the "Open Folder" option. From here I can build and compile it without any errors (CMake is using the IAR Compiler (iccarm.exe) as specified in the toolchain file). So far so good.
The problem is that IntelliSense, despite finding all necessary header files, shows lots of errors mainly related to "undefined __INTxx_T_TYPE__".

As far as i know thouse double underscores indicate that it's a compiler internal data type, which is not defined in any header file, which would also explain why IntelliSense reports that it's not defined (even if the compiler knows the type). I guess to counter this problem, IntelliSense does support different modes like "windows-msvc-x86" or "linux-gcc-arm". But there is no option for IAR compiler.

So my question: How can I get IntelliSense running in this project ? Is there a way to add a custom IntelliSense mode for the IAR compiler ? Can i add header files only for IntelliSense in which the missing types are defined ? Is there a way to tell IntelliSense not to worry about those types / ignore the types ?

Comment: it only understands microsoft & mingw internals. I do not think that it will know IAR internal types.

Comment: There is `__INTELLISENSE__` defined when IntelliSense is processing see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019  You could try adding some conditional symbols to shut up some of the most annoying errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just for the unlikely case someone has the same problem, here is my "solution" (sort of):

1. I created a header file with all the internal types used by IAR and called it "intellisenseHeader.h". You can find the internals here (https://www.gaio.co.jp/support/user/faq/winams/docs/sample_predef.pdf), but in my case i had to add some definitions by myself. The problem is now, that it won't compile anymore, because the IAR compiler, now finds 2 definitions (the internal definition and the one in the header file). So we need to fix this again:
2. I put the include inside a #ifdef USE_INTELLISENSE_HEADER.
3. I created two Visual Studio configurations. In the first one, CMake will set the preprocessor directive and the intellisenseHeader file will get included. In the other one i didn't set it.

So what's the effect of this ? If you are in the configuration, where the header is included, IntelliSense works but you can't compile. And if you are in the other one you can compile, but IntelliSense doesn't work anymore. So now i need to switch between the configurations, everytime i want to compile or write some code... Not the best solution but still better than nothing.

EDIT: Ok just realized you can use __INTELLISENSE__ as mentioned in @ Richard Critten comment, and therefore don't need to use multiple configs.